# Laravel 7 Cashier subscription: Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-7, laravel-cashier

I'm having 2 products here's one of them

[image]

I have implemented the default payment form of stripe https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js. User class uses billable like this

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
use Billable;
```

.env contains correct data

```
STRIPE_KEY=your-stripe-key
STRIPE_SECRET=your-stripe-secret
```

Now I'm trying to make the user subscribe to this plan this way:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe;
use App\User;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->subscription('prod_HeC7XMT2SVe21K')->create($request->stripeToken);
    }
}
```

But I get

```
Call to a member function create() on null
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Note: I didn't use the secret key anywhere except in the .env file as I followed some tutorials don't know if that's correct.

Comment: have you tried `$user->newSubscription('prod_HeC7XMT2SVe21K')->create($data['payment_method']);` ... Note `newSubscription` and create method will accept the payment method as first parameter and array of other parameters like email, phone (i.e user details) as second parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the subscription in the following way:

```
$subscription = $user->newSubscription('plan_name' , 'plan_id'); 
$subscription->create('payment_method', ['other_parameters']);
```

replace 
'plan_name' with the name of the plan created on stripe dashboard. 
'plan_id' with the id of the plan selected. 
'other_parameters' can include user's email, phone_number etc.